# send is not defined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I don't get how to fix the TypeError `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`
This is caused by the line where I get the channel `702825446248808519`

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['sug', 'suggestion'],
    description: 'Suggest something for the Bot',
    execute(client, message) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the Bot or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)

        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, })
            .then(async (collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                    message.reply("Your suggestion has been cancelled.")
                }
                else {
                    const embed = new RichEmbed()
                        .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .addField(`New Suggestion from:`, `**${message.author.tag}**`)
                        .addField(`Suggestion:`, `${collected.first().content}\n**Its your choice!**`)
                        .setColor('0x0099ff');
                    client.channels.get("702825446248808519").send(embed)

                    message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`)
                }
            })
    },
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. In which line is the error?  2. Are you passing the `message` argument to the `execute()` function?  3. Is there *really* a channel with ID 702825446248808519?

Comment: so the error somehow was because i put client in the execute(), now i removed it and added const Discord = require('discord.js'); and const client = new Discord.Client(); into the code but now the error is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null, and btw yes the channel with that ID exists

Comment: can you post your message event?

Comment: client.on('message', message => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
  || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

 if (!command) return;

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
 }

Comment: try {
     command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
     message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

Comment: That is the message event from the command handler, if you mean that, i dont have anything else i think

Comment: ok i fixed the "of null" error but now its: cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: You need to pass client in command.execute

Comment: here on SO it is important that you accept answers if they helped you, I've noticed you only upvote answers, so if any answers have fixed your issues then please accept them to let others know what worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get()` is not a method for [`ChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager), you need to use [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)

So your line `client.channels.get("702825446248808519").send(embed)` needs to be replaced with `client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519").send(embed)`