# bot's username is not defined

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I am getting this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` which is caused by `client.user.username` in `embed`'s `.setFooter()`.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['sug', 'suggestion'],
    description: 'Suggest something for the Bot',
    execute(message, client, args) {
        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        message.channel.send(`Please provide a suggestion for the Bot or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)

        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, })
            .then(async (collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                    message.reply("Your suggestion has been cancelled.")
                }
                else {
                    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setFooter(client.user.username, client.user.displayAvatarURL)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .addField(`New Suggestion from:`, `**${message.author.tag}**`)
                        .addField(`New Suggestion:`, `${collected.first().content}`)
                        .setColor('0x0099ff');
                    client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519").send(embed)

                    message.channel.send(`Your suggestion has been filled to the staff team. Thank you!`)
                }
            })
    },
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61464984/13176517)

> try { command.execute(message, args); } catch (error) { console.error(error); message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!'); } });

You are not passing `client` into `execute()`, you need to do that.

You also need to use `await` on `channels.fetch()` since it returns a promise so replace `client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519").send(embed)` with:

```js
const channel = await client.channels.fetch("702825446248808519")
channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: try {
     command.execute(message, client, args);
    } catch (error) {

Like that right? But now the error is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: client.channels.fetch(...).send is not a function, so it still has to do with client hasn't it?

Comment: Also, here on SO it is important that you accept answers if they helped you, I've noticed you only upvote answers, so if any answers have fixed your issues then please accept them to let others know what worked.

Comment: Thanks ok i will keep in mind and now everything works perfectly